# how to use GtkSource.FileLoader in python3

Tags: python-3.4, gtk3, gtksourceview

As the documentation suggests [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GtkSource-3.0/classes/FileLoader.html), have a GtkSource.View object, i've retrieved its buffer and passed in as parameter in GtkSource.FileLoader.new . Basically here is my code:

```
    # set file loader
    file = GtkSource.File()
    file.set_location(Gio.File.new_for_path('/home/ishan/Desktop/net_neutrality/index.html'))

    x = GtkSource.FileLoader.new(self.code.get_buffer(), file)
    #self.code refers to a GtkSource.View object
```

Now the main problem is, i see nothing loaded from the file. SourceView is blank. So am I supposed to call [GtkSource.FileLoader.load_async](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GtkSource-3.0/classes/FileLoader.html#GtkSource.FileLoader.load_async) in order to "sort of" trigger the loading? Or is it something else that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to call load_async to load the file to the buffer.